# Ormlite inside Intentservice - ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite, classcastexception, intentservice

I am trying to use Ormlite for Database handling from an intentservice. I have read about using an Application as subclass. I have tried the following

The application class:

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private volatile DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


    public DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
        if (databaseHelper == null) {
            databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
        }
        return databaseHelper;
    }
}
```

In the intent service I defined:

```
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
```

And in the onHandleIntent() method of the intentservice I have tried:

```
    databaseHelper = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getHelper();
```

However I am getting ClassCastException, from Application to MyApplication

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is ormlite code??? I don't think you need to do this if you are using ormlite

Comment: @PankajKumar Am using Ormlite inside the activities, but the activities need to extent OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper>. This solution is needed in order to make it work from the intentservice.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I was declaring the application in the manifest as a different one from my main application.
What I needed is to modify the main application in AndroidManifest.xml. I pointed the main application to the custom application (MyApplication) that I created
Add this:

```
<Application android:name=".MyApplication">
```